# Java generate random double between exclusive starting range and inclusive ending range

Tags: java, random

```java
double num = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
```

This creates random double between `[min, max)`. I would like to create random double between `(min, max]`.

I have seen an [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363732/17978724) that generates integers between `[min, max]`, but the number here is integer and the starting range is inclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double num = max - Math.random() * (max - min);
```

This will produce numbers whose upper limit, `max` is inclusive, but whose lower limit, `min` is exclusive, because `max` is returned when `Math.random()` returns zero.